# VirtualBox ErrorVkPhysicalDevice does not support GetPhysicalDeviceCalibrateableTimeDomainsKHR

Tags: virtualbox, nvidia, vulkan, archlinux

I used Arcolinux Hyprland in my i5 8th gen, gtx 1060 gpu system. Last time I used virtualbox with ubuntu server iso and it was working perfectly. Today I tried to launch virtualbox from the terminal because from rofi it wasn't responding, so the verbose showed this message as follows:

```
Qt WARNING: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
ERROR:ICD associated with VkPhysicalDevice does not support GetPhysicalDeviceCalibrateableTimeDomainsKHR
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I did remove all 3 virtualbox, virtualbox-dkms-host, virtualbox-host-iso packages and reinstall them but nothing is working.
All my drivers and packages are up-to-date by the way.

Comment: Notice: Only programming-related questions are on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Found the solution. I think it had to do something with the kernel and dkms things since on Feb 20, 2024 linux and linux-headers packages got updated. While installing virtualbox package, pacman offers 2 different options:

1. virtualbox-host-dkms,
2. virtualbox-host-moduels-arch.

Previously, no. 1 was installed in the system. I just removed all virtualbox packages

- virtualbox
- virtualbox-guest-iso

and reinstall virtualbox with the 2nd option (virtualbox-host-module-arch) and voila, it works! I just removed all the VM folders from my home just to be sure, don't know if that makes any difference or not.

Just in case, if you find that after launching Virtual Box and starting any VM (e.g. archlinux) shows any error especially the classic
**Virtualbox kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)** then please uninstall everything and install virtual box while pressing enter to automatically select the default value from the above 2 options and then later install virtualbox-guest-iso. It'll fix the rc--1908 issue and your VM will boot up.

Comment: The error is due to bug in `mesa 1:24.0.1-1` that got pushed to arch recently. In my case I could not use VirtualBox in VNC. Downgrading to version 23 solves the issue: `sudo pacman -U file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/mesa-23.1.4-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst`.